# Defining variables in a loop in Mathematica

Tags: for-loop, variables, wolfram-mathematica

I have a list of solutions Subscript[x, 1][t], i = 1,...,n (n given).

I would like to use these variables to define new variables such as:

```
i = 1;
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, 
 Subscript[X, i][t_] := Subscript[x, i][t] /. sol]
```

I know that this code is not working and I know why. However, I would like to ask you if there is a way how to define these variables at once (without having to define them one by one)?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

David.

Answer (score 1):

Your example code isn't quite complete enough that I can be certain this is correct.

Assuming you have previously defined something like this:

```
n=3;
Subscript[x,1][t]=1; Subscript[x, 2][t]=5; Subscript[x, 3][t]=7;
```

Try this

```
 (Subscript[X,#][t_]:=Subscript[x,#][t]/.sol)& /@ Range[n];
```

and that should define your functions of X.

Then you should be able to test that using this

```
Subscript[X,1][t]
```

to see if you have the correct definition.

Comment: If necessary you can force evaluation `(Subscript[X, #][t_] := Evaluate[Subscript[x, #][t]] /. sol) & /@ 
 Range[n]`